# Comparing two lists to find the difference

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have two grid controls that are the same table but since it is an audit trail history, some of the cell values for a column are different sizes than the original. This is messing up my synchronized scroll.

So what I am trying to do is set the column width equal to the larger column value between the two grids. This is how I am doing it so far:

```
 Private Sub GridView1_RowCellStyle(sender As Object, e As RowCellStyleEventArgs) Handles gvwOriginalAuditValues.RowCellStyle

    Dim originalColumnWidth As New List(Of Integer)()
    Dim modifiedColumnWidth As New List(Of Integer)()

    If gvwOriginalAuditValues.RowCount > 0 And gwvModifiedAuditValues.RowCount > 0 Then
        If gvwOriginalAuditValues.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle, e.Column) <> gwvModifiedAuditValues.GetRowCellDisplayText(0, e.Column.FieldName) Then
            e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        End If

        For Each col As DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn In gvwOriginalAuditValues.Columns
            originalColumnWidth.Add(col.Width)
        Next
        For Each col2 As DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn In gwvModifiedAuditValues.Columns
            modifiedColumnWidth.Add(col2.Width)
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Now the next step I am having trouble with is comparing the two lists (originalColumnWidth and modifiedColumnWidth). They will have the exact same number of columns, in the same order. So any ideas how I can compare the two lists, and when there is a difference between the two, change that column width to the larger value, so they equal each other?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To originalColumnWidth.Count
   if (originalColumnWidth(i) > modifiedColumnWidth(i)) Then
      modifiedColumnWidth(i) = originalColumnWidth(i)
   ElseIf (originalColumnWidth(i) < modifiedColumnWidth(i)) Then
      originalColumnWidth(i) = modifiedColumnWidth(i)
   End if
Next
```

Comment: This is just comparing the overall count of the list, which I already stated they will be equal to each other. Thanks for trying, though.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. Exactly, can you explain better what you need? I'l be happy to help

Comment: I was trying to go through each loop and compare where there are differences. When there is a difference record that position in both of the lists, as well as the values that are different. Then I want to go back in and change the lists to match identically with the larger value. I have figured out an easier way to handle what I'm looking for by creating a method to handle different events within the grid column itself. So, unless you just want to figure it out to figure it out, I don't think I'll be choosing this method anymore. Thank you :)